# How to create a webview on Android with required internet Connection message

Tags: android, android-webview

Hey guy i'm in little problem ..
i am able to create the **web-view in android**, but now i want to show the message for required internet connection.. someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check weather device has internet or not , try this

```
public static boolean hasActiveInternetConnection(Context context) {
if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
        urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
        urlc.connect();
        return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
    }
} else {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No network available!");
}
return false;
}
```

It will check for internet connection. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a method isConnected() :
 `public boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) MainActivityFragment.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }`

And Use it like this :

```
  if (isConnected()) {
                // Perform any task which require internet connection
            }
            else {


Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No internet connection found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```